# TFS VS2017 - team foundation shows folder difference, but all options to check out are grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I have 20+ projects in one solution. Suddenly one of the projects that I have used with TFS for years doesn't allow me to check out the code even though it does recognize the code difference between the server and my local version.

I tried to unload/reload the project, I checked the bindings and rebound the mapping, but the results are still the same.

Also, I see a weird "Object reference .. " error!

[PRINTSCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRs6H.png)

Comment: What's the exactly VS version do you use? What about creating a new workspace? Whatever, there's an related issue with the earlier version of Visual Studio 2017 and it's fixed in 15.2 version. So you can try to upgrade to the latest  version of VS ,then check it again.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I have 15.0. However, I can't upgrade to other versions as when we upgraded to 15.2, 3, 4 and the experimental one, our whole team couldn't work as visual studio would crash every 5-30 seconds, so after a week or so, we had to roll back - which was a lot of pain with 10 different workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio if you are not using
  the latest one.
- Try Running As Administrator (right-click Visual Studio and choose
  "Run As Administrator")
- Create a new workspace, map source to a new local folder.
- Close any instance and restart the VS.
- Delete folder `ComponentModelCache` under path
  `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{versio‌​n - 15 or 15_***}`. You can keep the rest and no settings get lost...

  Alternatively, use the [Clear MEF Component Cache](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache) extension.
- Delete the contents from the following folders: (To backup you can renam the Visualstudio & VSCommon dirs to VisualStudio_old & VSCommon_old)

  `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

  `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`
- Try to reset user data :

  Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

  `run devenv /resetuserdata`

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't update VS as all the next versions so far cause VS to crash within a minute (happening to 10 workstations).

I followed the path @Andy-MSFT provided except for upgrading and then I deleted the workspace. After getting a number of other errors, I was finally able to recreate the workspace and now it works.